# ASP.Net MVC 5 app talking to TCP Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, tcpclient

I developed an ASP.Net MVC 5 application hosted on Azure. It needs to exchange data with an accounting software that some of my clients use. This accounting software provides a TCP Server that runs somewhere in the LAN of my clients.

To communicate, I need the IP and the Port of the TCP Server but the TCPServer always gives the local IP so here are my questions:

1) is it possible for a web app like mine establish a communication with a TCPServer hosted at my clients office (and probably runs behind firewalls)

2) If I manage to find the real IP where the TCP Server lives, can this IP changes?

Basically, I am trying to find a elegant and easy way for my clients to setup the connection once within our web app to their Accounting Software Server.

Comment: You can use dyndns or another type of third party tool?. If the response is Yes, you will need to install dyndns on the TCPServer to make it reachable from outside, and then configure which ports will be open and who can access (your azure instance ip), this tool will handle dynamic ip changes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This accounting software provides a TCP Server that runs somewhere in
>   the **LAN** of my clients. To communicate, I need the IP and the Port of
>   the TCP Server but the TCPServer always gives the local IP

1. > is it possible for a web app like mine establish a communication with
   >   a TCPServer hosted at my clients office (and probably runs behind
   >   firewalls)

   From an external *network* (Azure)? No, not unless you get into networking matters that *would allow* some external access (VPN, port forwarding, etc.). Alternatively "some API" that would act like same (aka "gateway" *instead* of some *direct* access).

   I will defer to Azure experts on [Azure VPN Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways)
2. > If I manage to find the real IP where the TCP Server lives, can this
   >   IP changes ?

   That's a question that can only be addressed by your client/IT....

Comment: Thank you. Yes it helps!